# How to use personal apple id for ipa signature

Tags: ios, ipa, codesign

I've seen [SideLoady](https://sideloadly.io/), and [AltStore](https://altstore.io/) all use regular Apple ids directly to re-sign the ipa. The re-signed ipa can be installed on non-jailbroken iPhone devices. The downside is that it only has a 7-day expiration date

Does apple provide similar apple id signature ipa documentation?

I would like to use my personal Apple Id to sign the ipa and then install the app on my iPhone, using the script to automatically re-sign the ipa

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use your apple id for signature. Install 3uTools and go to IPA signature tab on toolbox. Choose ur file. Then go down and look for "Sign with Apple ID" save ur apple id there and then wait for it to sign it. You can also go to "iDevice" tab and go to "Apps" section and import the signatured ipa file there. I don't know if they expire because i never got it expired.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I hope to use scripts or interfaces to automate signing